# iPhone 4 and Cisco WRT320N connection issues

Tags: iphone

I've recently acquired an iPhone 4 (iOS 4.0.1) and hooked it up to my Cisco WRT320N wireless router.

For whatever reason, my iPhone drops of the network constantly.  Sometimes before I can even load a single page in Safari.  When it does work, its quite slow.

This behavior is independent of distance from the router, and the iPhone is showing full bars for the network when its connected.

The router is configured as follows:

- Wireless Band: 2.4 GHz
- Network Mode: Wireless-G only
- Channel: Auto
- Security Mode: WPA Personal
- Firmware Version: v1.0.03  (which seems to be the lastest)

There's no MAC filtering or the like going on.  A laptop was recently used to connect to this configuration - without issue - so I'm fairly certain this is an iPhone-specific problem.

So, any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end reverting to WEP solved the issue.

Not pleased security-wise, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try [resetting your network settings](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10115213-233.html). That usually works for me when I have any connectivity issues (WiFi/ 3G/ ....tethering (hee hee))

Hope this helps!